# PATCH OPA Data when array data based on id

Tags: open-policy-agent

I have data loaded to OPA server something like this :

```
{
    "admin": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "action": "create",
            "object": "order"
        },
        {
             "id": 2,
            "action": "read",
            "object": "order"
        }
    ],
    "user": [
        {
             "id": 1,
            "action": "read",
            "object": "order"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to patch particular record based on Id. If I want to update admin[0].object where admin[0].Id=2. how I can update ?

I tried below but getting error :  "message": "json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []types.PatchV1"

Below Request I tried :

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'http://localhost:8181/v1/data/permission' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--data '{
  "admin": [
    {
      "op": "test",
      "path": "/admin",
      "value": [{"id": 2}]
    },
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "path": "/admin/1/object",
      "value": "test1"
    }
  ]
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OPA supports the test operation, but even if it did, you're query wouldn't match as you'd need to compare to the whole value, which in your example would be:

```json
{
    "id": 2,
    "action": "read",
    "object": "order"
}
```

It's probably a better idea to do this in two requests — one for querying for the index, i.e.

```
POST /v1/query HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "query": "data.permission.admin[x].id == 2"
}
```

Which would give you a response containing the `x` binding, i.e. the index of the item that matched:

```json
{
    "result": [
        {
            "x": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

You could then patch the object at that index:

```
PATCH /v1/data/permission/admin/1 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "path": "/object",
      "value": "test1"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on json-patch, but I don't think it's possible to select an array element based on an attribute inside the element; only by direct indexing (although I might be mistaken, which would invalidate the rest of this answer).

The unmarshal error you probably get because the json-patch data is expected to be an array of operations, e.g.:

```json
[
  {"op": "test", "path": "/admin/1", "value": {"id": 2}},
  {"op": "replace", "path": "/admin/1", "value": {"id": 2, "foo": "bar"}}
]
```

(not sure OPA supports the `test` op)

For small arrays, you could fetch the entire array, figure out the index of the element to change, and replace that (e.g. `"path": "/admin/<i>"`). But this wouldn't scale very well with the size of data stored in OPA; and I'd be concerned with race conditions if there are multiple clients.

Is there a reason outside of your hands that the data is an array rather than a dictionary? If not, and if `id` is intended to be unique, perhaps you could consider refactoring your data into a dictionary, and include the id in the path of the op; e.g.:

data:

```json
{
    "admin": {
        "foo": {
            "action": "create",
            "object": "order"
        },
        "bar": {
            "action": "read",
            "object": "order"
        }
    }
}
```

json-patch:

```
[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/admin/foo",
        "value": {
            "x": "y"
        }
    }
]
```